# Not able to read json property in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting this response from a API:

```
var ob = {"bytesSent":1087,"responseCode":200,"response":"{\"id\":\"4b1e9740-6059-11e5-9454-518e45576d76\"}","objectId":""}
```

If i do `ob.response.id` it show undefined. What might be the trick ?

I tried `var rss=JSON.parse(ob);` but it show `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Comment: `ob.response` is a JSON string

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(r)` at the appropriate point? If `r` is literally a string containing your first code example, you'll need to remove the "var ob = " from the beginning of the string before parsing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`response` is another unparsed JSON (string) inside your api response. You need to parse `response`:

```
var ob = {"bytesSent":1087,"responseCode":200,"response":"{\"id\":\"4b1e9740-6059-11e5-9454-518e45576d76\"}","objectId":""}     
var ob2 = JSON.parse(ob.response);
console.log(ob2.id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem is `ob.response` is `JSON string` and not just `JSON`.

```js
var ob = {
  "bytesSent": 1087,
  "responseCode": 200,
  "response": "{\"id\":\"4b1e9740-6059-11e5-9454-518e45576d76\"}",
  "objectId": ""
};

alert(typeof ob.response);
alert(JSON.parse(ob.response).id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Ob variable please check bellow code.

```
var ob = {"bytesSent":1087,"responseCode":200,"response":{"id":"4b1e9740-6059-11e5-9454-518e45576d76"},"objectId":""}  
alert(ob.response.id);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1w5Lms5n/